# Deciphering Old Runes (or: What's The Program?)

Tags: cipher, visual, computer-science

**Some background**:

I was going through some old photos of mine, and I came across old doodles I had made during algorithms class (while getting my bachelor's in computer science).

I remember these scribbles being some attempt at inventing some kind of magic system that works like programming, for using in a story or video game one day. I ended up forgetting all about it, and now I don't remember what the symbols mean.

**So**:

Can you figure out what the following doodles mean?

(Disclaimer: I doubt these bits are complete programs. They're probably just snippets of some larger magic/code I was thinking of.)

[image: First bunch of runes]

[image: Second bunch of runes]

I haven't yet given it a shot yet (so I'm not even sure yet what the correct answer is - yet).
Figured you guys might enjoy it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [image: probable decipher]

///

> Too little information given, anything here would be a speculation. I assume symbols on the right are names for new functions, on the left is their definitions. 
>  
>  if (F1 is true) (set F2 false, return U), if (F1 is false) (return L) 
>  if (F1 is false, return L), is (F1 is true)(set F2 false, return U) 
>  
>  Than you just rewrote the second (equivalent) function two times more. The last one is 
>  if (D1 is true) (return D).

Comment: You're absolutely right about too little information. I myself don't know what this means, and *I* wrote it! Your answer is very good, although I don't think it's what I meant at the time. This language was meant to be some kind of magic language that can affect the real world.

Comment: I've been thinking about it, and given the fact that this isn't a "fair" riddle with a definitive answer, any answer that solves the runes (whether it's my original - and forgotten - intention or not) should be accepted.

Comment: This looks like it could be a partial encoding for a light-seeking robot, where the registers represent sensors, and the actions are motions.